# Can not access tomcat's default page

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, configuration, internet

I am quite new to Tomcat. I use win XP. I have installed Tomcat 7.0.3, started it.

I have started a browser, go to localhost:8080 and I can see the congratulations page, saying that tomcat is working.

I opened a what-is-my-ip webpage to retreive my Ip, took my smartphone, get a broswer, set address to http://[myip]:8080, but it says that the server is down.

I added an exception for port 8080 in Win Firewall. Then checking the Tomcat localhost_access_log shows no request apart from what I started from the browser of the host computer.

The computer I run tomcat on is connected to the internet via USB wireless modem, so it is very modest upload capacity, but the congratulations page is simple.

What have I done wrong?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, as much I can understand, the issue is that you are running your Tomcat server on localhost only, and not on the interface IP, which you have tried with mobile.

To verify the same, go to the same machine, where tomcat is working and out this in your browser `http://[myip]:8080`, instead of `http://localhost:8080`.

If the site doesn't open, then the issue is the same what I am expecting. To fix it, try to find where you can change the configs so that apache run both on localhost and you IP.

If the site works, then the issue is with the firewall, and you need to look into the windows firewall and see what is blocking your requests.